# How to rename view of mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I have created multiple views now for a separation i wanted to apply prefix vw_ so collections and view could be separated. I try to see in documentation at here https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/master/views/#modify-the-source-of-a-view
but there is nothing about rename views.

is it possible via Mongodb compass IDE?

if not than how we could achieve by command line?

Comment: Yon cannot rename views in MongoDB. Drop the view and create a new one with new name.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit thanks did search a lot and finally did drop and create new one thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Renaming views in MongoDB is not possible yet. You have to drop the existing one and create a new one.

Answer (score 1):

You can duplicate a view assigning a new name, then drop the original